# Tableview set row height dynamically based on content in swift?

Tags: swift, height, uitableview

I am struck in setting tableview cell row height in swift , On scrolling the row height is changing, please check the screen shot.[image]

For the first time its scrolling perfect on scrolling multiple times the height is not proper. I am using too many custom tableview cells
In viewDidLoad
I added this

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

and also added these delegate methods.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Can anyone guide me to achieve this in proper way.

Comment: Please put this in your **cellForRowAtIndexPath**  method `yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0` And 
`yourLabel.sizeToFit()`

Comment: this is not the with one label. I used two many labels.

Comment: have you give proper constraints between image and label?

Comment: so your all labels , will be extand to multiple line?

Comment: @iParesh.. means i am setting all constraints

Comment: @iDeveloper.. yes they are extended to multiple line

Comment: I mean , If you have five label , all labels will be extended according to contain Every label ?

Comment: @iDeveloper. i am not getting what ur asking

Comment: @iDeveloper. The space in screenshot u can see shared this post & in other cell the label not exist also space occurs.